# (Done) How can this question regarding ADHD in the workplace be improved?

Tags: discussion, offtopic

[How do people with ADD manage in the tech industry](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/113597/how-do-people-with-add-manage-in-the-tech-industry)

This question was voted to close as 'too broad', but has attracted several upvotes and answers.

I have ADHD myself - so I have an interest in this question.

Personally - I think it's a perfectly acceptable question - though I'd argue that he should break his paragraphs into bullet points to more clearly communicate the issues he is dealing with.

One thing I suspect is that people without ADHD are just not aware of the ongoing recurring issues that people with ADHD often face, and so don't understand the context of the question.

Answer (score 2):

I voted to reopen, dealing with a particular disability is not too broad a subject  to answer.